# Custom button URL hack - how to send to specific email address

Tags: email, custom-button, button

I tried to send a email from a custom button in opportunity, but I can't send to a specific email, I want send automaticaly when I click in the button.
I try this but don't work. I can't send to a specific email if don't have a contact into lookup field?

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}&p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&p2_lkid=a@a.com&template_id=00X11000000MMCZ&p5=&save=1')
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you say specific email, do you mean a fixed email address?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're correct that you probably need your button to have a reference context of a look-up to a contact, not just an email address. You'd need to verify this by looking at the code for the email template your button is linked to.

To make it work properly for your purposes, you might want clone it and modify it to use the OpportunityID as the WhatID of your email (or subject) and then your contact would be the WhoId.

Comment: how can I do that? WhoId?

Comment: Find the visual force template whose `id=00X11000000MMCZ`, open it, select clone, then save as. One of the fields might be the WhoId. The WhoId is the contactId that a Task, Email, Activity, etc is related to. Its useful for tracking purposes.

Comment: Not a visalforce Template, is a custom template.
Just Work with visualforce template?

Comment: No, clone the custom template.

Comment: Yes I clone that, but can't find the WhoId

Comment: As I previously indicated, the WhoId may or may not have been included in coding the original template. The main thing is that you'll need to pass a ContactId with your Button to the template, not just the Opp Id.